# Estimating supra-exponential decay (finding a function for simulations)

Tags: exponential-function, simulation, parameter-estimation

I have a time-series that appears to decay supra-exponentially. [image: Plotting it with iterations of Log10 of Time Series y-value] results in better fitness to a straight line. After taking $\log(\log(\log(y)))$, I have a great fit. This time series represents the probability over time that an event occurs (e.g., a player will continue a conversation). I need to find a function that can approximate this behavior so that I can attempt to simulate interactions. How may I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $\beta_1$ and $\beta_0$ are the coefficients of the regression in the fourth figure. What would be wrong with the function $y=\exp(\exp(\exp (\beta_1 x + \beta_0)))$?

Comment: How do I find $\beta_{1}$ and $\beta_0$ in that case? Thanks.

Comment: $\beta_1$ and $\beta_0$ are slope and intercept of the line you show on the fourth (lower, right) figure with title "5(d)". They are the result of your regression.

Comment: OK, I feel sheepish. Thanks!